# How is negative zero used in this context?

Tags: c, networking

```
struct in_addr ipv4;

ipv4.s_addr = (uint32_t)(-0)
```

Comment: Is this on some sort of embedded device that has ones-complement integers?

Comment: Apparently some pair-programmers got into an argument about whether to use -1 or ~0 in this situation and decided to compromise.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP misread the code, and the actual code included `~0` and not `-0`.

Answer (score 6):

That's strange, usually arithmetic is implemented through [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) so you don't effectively have a negative representation of `0`.

In a **One's Complement** version the negative `0` is instead stored as `0xFFFFFFFF` so you would have `255.255.255.255` when converted to an ipv4 address after the cast to unsigned int.

While in a normal architecture using `-0` to cast it to an unsigned int should just give you `0x00000000`.

Comment: Any architecture will result in -0 cast to an unsigned int being 0x00000000.

Answer (score 1):

This makes not much sense, since the standard says about the exact width integer types

> These types are optional. However, if
>   an implementation provides integer
>   types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64
>   bits, no padding bits, and (for the
>   signed types) that have a two's
>   complement representation, it shall
>   define the corresponding typedef
>   names.

So first of all there is no negative zero for any of these signed types and then even less for the unsigned ones. In any case for the assignment that you show a simple `0` would be as good, or `UINT32_C(0)` if you want to be picky.

Answer (score 0):

It would be used to get the signed value of the unsigned integer, or, one more than the maximum value of a signed integer.

The `uint32_t` would be casting it to an unsigned integer, while the `-0` would be forcing it to be negative, flipping the signed bit, and returning the unsigned value with it flipped.

[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) explains signed integers.

Comment: This is only true for one's complement.